# Playing with LESS - optimize css generated by passing ruleset to mixin

Tags: css, less

I'm just playing with LESS lately. I wanted to generate rules for elements with numeric ID. At some stage I got code like this:

```
@myRule: {padding: 0;};

.myLoop(@c, @rules) when (@c >= 0) {
    .myLoop((@c - 1), @rules);
    &[id*=@{c}] { @rules(); }
    &[name*=@{c}] { @rules(); }
}

.myClass {
  .myLoop(2, @myRule);
}
```

which compiles to

```
.myClass[id*=0] {
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass[name*=0] {
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass[id*=1] {
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass[name*=1] {
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass[id*=2] {
  padding: 0;
}
.myClass[name*=2] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

My question is: can I in any way make it compile to sth like this:

```
.myClass[id*=0],
.myClass[name*=0],
.myClass[id*=1],
.myClass[name*=1],
.myClass[id*=2],
.myClass[name*=2] {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I was looking for something like 'extending mixins`, 'parametric extend' or 'extending ruleset' but all lead to issues that are either 'wontfix' or 'nice-to-have' :-) So I guess it's not yet possible, but I would just like to reach out to people more familiar with less then I am, to be sure.

Comment: I think this is tricky (and may need a very hacky solution) unless you decide to write a base rule and then extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, neither extending parametric mixins nor scoped extend are possible currently, so the easiest method to achieve the result is to extend a dummy ruleset. E.g.:

```
.my-repeat(@i, @f) when (@i >= 0) {
    .my-repeat((@i - 1), @f);
    &[id*=@{i}], &[name*=@{i}] {@f();}
}

.my-class-style {
    padding: 0;  
}

.my-class {
    .my-repeat(2, {
        &:extend(.my-class-style); 
    });
}
```

where `.my-class-style` is the dummy selector to appear in the resulting CSS too.

Comment: Thank you. This is working perfectly fine my lessc 2.5.3, but not on lesstester which is using lessc 1.7.5 (it generates something, but some rules are empty), and fails http://winless.org, but I cannot find what lessc they use. I guess winless uses <1.7.0 because detached ruleset support was added then, but I can't figure out what feature added after 1.7.5 makes this work. I walked through changelog and only saw in v 2.4.0 - "Extends on a selector joined with & now work better" :-). Thanks again :)